# how to tell netbeans to store glassfish 3 password

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-3, netbeans-6.9

Every time I start netbeans, the first time I launch a web application which is deployed on a Glassfish 3 or Glassfish 3.1 server where I set a password, netbeans asks for my credentials.

This is (and needs to be) a custom glassfish installation.

I know it is possible to tell netbeans not to ask, because it is like it when installing the glassfish that is bundled with netbeans.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetBeans does not do anything to remember the password for GlassFish Server 3.0 and 3.1.  It doesn't send a password when commands are sent to the running server via HTTP and so, the server returns a 401.  The IDE presents the authorization dialog and retries the HTPP admin command.

There is an open enhancement request for this feature. http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=166648

Comment: Netbeans has the option to store password for Glassfish 2 quite annoying that there is no option to store password for Glassfish 3.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but it might be a bug (in which case it would be great if would file an issue).

The default installation of GlassFish has no password set for the admin user (so no password is required).

I recommend:

- use a local GlassFish installation with no password for development (deploy with NetBeans)
- use a password on your productive GlassFish installation, deploy from your continuous integration server (such as Hudson)

Comment: Thanks. This is a local installation, with a password (which is what I want). I just want Netbeans to store it somewhere and to stop asking.